# Disable Custom Directive When Ng-Select Receives Empty Array AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is it somehow possible to "disable" a custom directive in Angular if an ng-select located within that directive receives an empty array?

Namely, consider the following code that creates an expand-collapse area on the page. I populate the content area of the area with a list of things. Now, sometimes there are items on the list, yet in other cases the list is empty. The problem is that when the list is empty, the custom directive  still leaves a "+" sign on the page to indicate expandability. It is bad tone to keep it there and not have anything come up when the user clicks on it. How could I disable this directive entirely or get rid of the "+" created by it when the list is empty? The latter is my ultimate goal in this case.

```
<span ng-controller="ListChildren">
                <v-accordion class="vAccordion--default" style="width:80%; margin: auto">
                      <v-pane>
                        <v-pane-header>

                        </v-pane-header>

                        <v-pane-content>

                            <span ng-repeat="child in childs">
                                <a href="/#/activity/{{child._id}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-block badge" ng-style="{'background-color' : child.color, 'color' : child.colorTitle, 'border-color' : child.colorBorder}" ng-class="{'pulsation' : pulse , 'nonpulsation' : !pulse}" ng-init="pulse = false">
                    {{child.title}}

                                        <span class="badge" ng-style="{'background-color' : child.colorSupport, 'color' : child.colorFont}">Current: {{counter | secondsToHHmmss }}</span>
                                        <span class="badge" ng-style="{'background-color' : child.colorSupport, 'color' : child.colorFont}">Total: {{child.totalTime | secondsToHHmmss }}</span>    
                                </a>
                                <a ng-click="toggle =!toggle; $parent.pulse = !$parent.pulse; toggleTimer()" ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-pause' : toggle , 'glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle' : !toggle}"></a>
                                <a href="/#/activity/delete/{{child._id}}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a> 

                            </span>

                        </v-pane-content>

                      </v-pane>
                </v-accordion>
    </span>
```

Comment: You can use the same variable where you get the ng-select items and add an ng-if to the root element of the directive's template so the entire directive will not be added to the Dom if it is false

Comment: That did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code:

```
            <span ng-controller="ListChildren">
            <v-accordion class="vAccordion--default" style="width:80%; margin: auto" ng-if="childs.length > 0">
                  <v-pane>
                    <v-pane-header>

                    </v-pane-header>

                    <v-pane-content>

                        <span ng-repeat="child in childs">
                            <a href="/#/activity/{{child._id}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-block badge" ng-style="{'background-color' : activity.color, 'color' : activity.colorTitle, 'border-color' : activity.colorBorder}" ng-class="{'pulsation' : pulse , 'nonpulsation' : !pulse}" ng-init="pulse = false">
                {{child.title}}

                                    <span class="badge" ng-style="{'background-color' : activity.colorSupport, 'color' : activity.colorFont}">Current: {{counter | secondsToHHmmss }}</span>
                                    <span class="badge" ng-style="{'background-color' : activity.colorSupport, 'color' : activity.colorFont}">Total: {{activity.totalTime | secondsToHHmmss }}</span>   
                            </a>
                            <a ng-click="toggle =!toggle; $parent.pulse = !$parent.pulse; toggleTimer()" ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-pause' : toggle , 'glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle' : !toggle}"></a>
                            <a href="/#/activity/delete/{{child._id}}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a> 

                        </span>

                    </v-pane-content>

                  </v-pane>
            </v-accordion>
</span>
```